# Is it safe to run two installers simultaneously?

Tags: macos, install

Is it safe to run two installers simultaneously? Or is it safer to run one by one(maybe installers changes to write on same file)?

Comment: Only one package will be installed at a time, in the order in which you started them.

Comment: As far as I know you can run two installers (or more) at the same time, but the installation process' of packages is executed one at a time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Installer won't let you install two programs simultaneously, so the question is moot. Click Install on as many packages as you wish and Installer.app will queue them up and install them individually.

[image]